# Results show \n instead of actual new line in Python

Tags: python, newline

Starting with 2 different strings I'm trying to iterate over string1 n times and compare the substring with string2 to see if it matches any substrings in that string. If the substring matches, it's then appended to a list. My question is how do I get the list to print newlines instead of \n that is saved to the list in some substrings.

Example
substring length 3

string1:

```
Yo.
dey do!!

yo'yo. yoyo.
```

string 2:

```
yo.
dey do!!

yo'yo. yoyo.
```

My results are:

```
o.\n
.\nd
\nde
dey
ey 
y d
 do
do!
o!!
!!\n
!\n\n
\n\ny
\nyo
yo'
o'y
'yo
yo.
o. 
. y
 yo
yoy
oyo
o.
```

The correct results should be:

```
!!

o.

'yo
!


yo.
.
d


y
dey
yoy
o. 
ey 

de
y d

yo
. y
yo'
oyo
 yo
o'y
o!!
 do
do!
```

Here is the code:

```
def substrings(a, b, n):
"""Return substrings of length n in both a and b"""

all_sub = list()
i = 1
for h in range(len(a)):
    i = 1
    sub = a[h]
    if h+n > len(a):
        n = len(a) - h
    while i < n:
        sub += str(a[h+i])
        i += 1
        if i == n:
            if sub in b:

                all_sub.append(sub)
all_sub = list(dict.fromkeys(all_sub))
return all_sub

# Compare files
    if args["lines"]:
        matches = lines(file1, file2)
    elif args["sentences"]:
        matches = sentences(file1, file2)
    elif args["substrings"]:
        matches = substrings(file1, file2, args["substrings"])

    # Output matches, sorted from longest to shortest, with line endings escaped
    for match in sorted(matches, key=len, reverse=True):
        print(match.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r"))


def positive(string):
    """Convert string to a positive integer."""
    value = int(string)
    if value <= 0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("invalid length")
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why do `match.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r")` which replaces all the newlines, if you do want to print the newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `\n` with `\\n` will print `\n` where you have a newline character.

Change `match.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r")` to just `match` to stop escaping the newlines.